# Update the list of download servers

Tags: 16.04, mirrors

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. As you might know, there is a GUI tool that lets you choose the fastest download server.

But the list of servers is outdated. It contains some mirrors which no longer work (e.g. `ftp.iib.ac.in`). Also it doesn't include a lot of mirrors that are present on [Ubuntu Mirrors page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).

I can understand why the mirrors registered after release of Ubuntu 16.04 are not on the list ( e.g: [This](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntu.mirror.snu.edu.in-archive) and [This](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirrors.bangmod.cloud-archive). Registered in Jan 2017 ). But there are some mirrors registered long before April 2016 not on the list ( specifically [this one](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.0x.sg-archive). I use it).

So how do I update that list ? I am wondering if any newly added mirrors can give me faster speed.

Edit : I know that I can add the mirror manually to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. That what I'm using right now.

Comment: It would be good if the Synaptic maintainers could add a means to update this list or override as per the install.

Answer (score 1):

### Add a new mirror to the list

To add a new mirror URL to the list in the Software & Updates program, you can edit the mirror list directly:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.mirrors
```

and add the requisite line. Locate the correct section (lloks like the `LOD:SG` in your example: `http://mirror.0x.sg/ubuntu/`) and simply add it.

Launch Software & Updates again, and run the mirror list test.

### Manual update of existing mirrors

Otherwise you can update your mirrors manually via a command line:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In nano, type `Ctrl` + `\` (shortcuts at the bottom, the `^` means Ctrl , `M-` is Alt)

Type the string you want to replace (eg, `gb.archive.ubuntu.com`) and press enter

Then type the string you want (eg `mirror.0x.sg`), return

Then "A"

That should re-write all the URLs in the file.

Comment: I did a bit of digging around ; edited the answer.